# How does the scale function in Kubernetes ensure that the current task or request is completed when scaling down?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, hpa, horizontalpodautoscaler

Will unfinished tasks in the container be terminated when scaling down in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will unfinished tasks in the container be terminated when scaling down in Kubernetes?

Yes, to manage it you have a few options or best practices to follow.

You can check for **termination with grace**

Default value is 30 seconds so if it's taking longer than **30** seconds make sure you are setting it.

Add and manage the **terminationGracePeriodSecond** into the **YAML** config

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace